# onGetSentenceSuggestions suggestions are always empty

Tags: android

I'm trying to use google's spell checker service for OCR post processing.

I'm running a tutorial downloaded from github:
https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-SpellingCheckerFramework/blob/master/Spellings/app/src/main/java/com/hathy/spellings/SpellingsClient.java#L4

(I also tried other versions and read all posts I could find online on this issue).

No matter what I do the suggestions always return **empty**.
I see the same behavior both on emulator and on my Samsung phone.

What am I missing? It seems as if the dictionary it is using is empty..

Answer (score 0):

Samsung devices return empty suggestions unfortunately, but there shouldn't be a problem with emulators. I just tested this on the latest Q emulator:

```
val tsm = getSystemService(Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE) as TextServicesManager
val spellCheck = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, null, ...listener..., true)
spellCheck.getSentenceSuggestions(arrayOf(TextInfo("hllo")), 3)
```

and got suggestions `hello`, `bolo`, `hook`

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I noticed. If I call `spellCheckerSession.getSentenceSuggestions(...)` right after I turn on the device, I get no suggestions. But if I do the same after opening Gboard, I get the suggestions. Just opening a web browser and tapping on the search box (to bring up Gboard) is sufficient.

While you are at it, you might want to check the spell checker is selected.

```
Settings -> System -> Languages & input -> Spell checker ->
    Use spell checker [make sure it's selected]
    Default spell checker -> Gboard spell checker
```

I suspect that the Spell Check Service (i.e. `com.android.inputmethod.latin.spellcheck.AndroidSpellCheckerService`) doesn't start until Gboard becomes active.